# Maintaining DC voltage with more batteries

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, low-power, discharge

I have a circuit which i am powering with two 1.5V AA batteries that dies at 2.6V volt as the battery discharges. Reading around, i realized that even though there is energy in the batteries, my circuit is unable to draw it.

[image: discharge curve of a AA cell]

Is there a circuit that can come between say four 1.5V AA cells totaling 6V and my core circuit that can somehow 'maintain' a near-3V supply?

How does one solve these problems in industry? Pardon my ignorance, i come from much higher in the stack. :)

Comment: Google up the *buck-boost regulator*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the simple. Since you are pretending to use 4 batteries, arrange them on two pairs and connect them on parallel. You will still get 3V, but with the double of capacity (so half the discharge time of your bank).

For your knowledge, I suggest, for this voltage drop (6V to 3V), to do a search for buck converters. Do not try linear voltage regulators, or you will have worst autonomy even with 4 batteries than the original arrangement (2 batteries).

Comment: Photon was faster. I was still writing the answer.

Comment: Photons are generally pretty fast......

Comment: haha! 
sure they are!